# How do I add an element to an array thats in a different class in Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

so I have this array in a class called Park:

```
private Product[] stock = new Product[MAX_PROD];
```

In another class called Test(I have Park extended to test), I have these elements that I trying to add to the array, but it never works. This is how it looks:

These are the variables for sedan "public Sedan(double price, int quantity, String make, String model, int year, String
color)"

```
public class AutoParkInventoryTestProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AutoPark park1 = createPark1();
        System.out.println(park1.getName() + "'s Stock Is:");
        park1.displayAllProducts();
        System.out.println();

    }
    public static AutoPark createPark1() {
        AutoPark park1 = new AutoPark("Carleton AutoPark");

        Sedan s1 = new Sedan(100, 10, "Ford", "Model-1", 2018, "White");
        Sedan s2 = new Sedan(200, 10, "Honda", "Model-2", 2019, "Red");
        park1.addProduct(s1);
        park1.addProduct(s2);
        return park1;
```

Sedan is a different class btw.

This is one of the red errors I get before I run my code:

```
Required type:
Product
Provided:
Sedan
```

Sorry for the lack of information I gave initially, this is how addProduct looks:

```
public boolean addProduct(Product p) {
    if (currentStock < MAX_PROD - 1) {
        stock[currentStock++] = p;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You didn't show us the definition of `Sedan`, the definition of the `park1` variable, or the definition of the type of that variable.

Comment: What are your class definitions?

Comment: Is a "red error" what an IDE is highlighting? Can you tell what the actual error is? Your edit is a little helpful, but I think you'll need to add more information about your classes. Like what is `park1` and what does `addProduct` do?

Comment: You obviously can't; the point of declaring your 'stock' variable to be of type Product[], is that it is an array of products. You can't add a non-product to it. The fix is likely that you intended for class 'Sedan' to be a subtype of Product, e.g. by writing 'public class Sedan extends Product {}'. At that point, a sedan is a product, so, you can add it.

Comment: if Product and Sedan implement a common interface/class then they'd be interchangeable I guess.